# Does the Compatibility View meta tag still work with IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have several sites developed in DotNetNuke and their site nav menu is broken in IE 10 & 11 (I haven't tried 9 yet, but it works in IE 8).  I have found the meta tag to force compatibility mode in IE, however, when I implement this, it does not work.  I am using IE 11 to test with.  Does this meta tag still work?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I have also tried several variations of it, to no avail.  I have also tried implementing HTTP response headers in IIS 7.  Still no joy.  However, if I configure IE for compatibility view in the software itself (IE 11), adding the domain of the website to show in compatibility view, the website menu renders perfectly.

Is there a new way in IE 11 to force compatibility view in the code of the website or some other way?  TIA!

Comment: X-UA-Compatible is not the same thing as Compatibility View. [The latter specifically refers to an IE7 emulation layer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680497/which-engine-is-used-by-ie-compatibility-view/24680739#24680739) If I'm not wrong, the header should still work in IE11, although it is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's no wonder Microsoft and IE have fallen so far in popularity with their web browser software.  My websites still work just fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.  It's pretty bad when you have the 3rd popular browser when it ships with the OS.  There is no easy fix for IE.  It has always been in a world all of it's own.  http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Good thing Project Spartan is coming.

Comment: start by validating your webpage markup at validator.w3.org/nu

Comment: see http://w3fools.com for edification about the legitimacy of the w3schools website's content.

Comment: The Compatibility View button basically was the same as setting x-ua-compatible to `"IE=EmulateIE7"`.  If you use that value for your meta element, you should see similar results.  (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) Having said that, you really don't want to do this, as it means you're using old markup.  Better to switch to HTML5 doctype and support IE11 fully.